# How do I check if a VARCHAR column has control characters in it?

Tags: sql-server

How do I check if a `VARCHAR(MAX)` `column` has `ASCII Control Characters` in SQL Server?

Specifically I am looking for the presence of `0x01` `SOH`. Will this code work, it is copied from an example where they check for `LF` character i.e `CHAR(13)`

```
SELECT * FROM notes where content LIKE '%' + CHAR(1) + '%';
```

In any case I would like to get a generic query  for all the `Control Characters` instead of a hard-coding like this.

Comment: Is this a replica of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655909/whats-the-best-way-to-identify-hidden-characters-in-the-result-of-a-query-in-sq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found others that might have had a similar questions,

Before I go on... dont forget about [Collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508(v=sql.105).aspx).

That alone can make your life a nightmare,
If you have differences between Server level / Database level / Column level / Expression level, can cause strange behaviour and incorrect query results,if not properly managed.

I would suggest a regex expression to find what you are looking for.

Found on: [How to compare Unicode characters in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4319585/1896134)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_question WHERE question LIKE N'%é%'
```

Found on: [How can I find Unicode/non-ASCII characters in an NTEXT field in a SQL Server 2005 table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/687093/1896134):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers
(
    number  INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (number)
)
GO
DECLARE @i INT

SET @i = 0

WHILE @i < 1000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers (number) VALUES (@i)

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
GO

SELECT *,
    T.ID, N.number, N'%' + NCHAR(N.number) + N'%'
FROM
    dbo.Numbers N
INNER JOIN dbo.My_Table T ON
    T.description LIKE N'%' + NCHAR(N.number) + N'%' OR
    T.summary LIKE N'%' + NCHAR(N.number) + N'%'
and t.id = 1
WHERE
    N.number BETWEEN 127 AND 255
ORDER BY
    T.id, N.number
GO
```

Some Documentation from Microsoft: [Pattern Matching in Search Conditions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(SQL.90).aspx)

And alternatively: [Search Text with Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx)

In my experince with mysql there are build in functions like so:

```
SELECT '\0x01' REGEXP '[[:graph:]]'; -- returns true
SELECT '\0x01' REGEXP '[[:print:]]'; -- returns false
```

As a start, I Hope this helps!

Comment: Control Characters seems like a different beast altogether!